# querying virtual/external dataverse tables in SSMS, Power BI or anything other than Power Platform UI

Tags: dataverse, power-platform, microsoft-fabric

I want to query my dataverse tables in something other than the power platform UI, which is limiting.

I can connect to the dataverse using sql server management server & power bi, but none of the virtual/external tables show up.

is there a way to see these virtual/external tables outside of the dataverse?

Answer (score 0):

The TDS endpoint (which is what SQL Management Studio and Power BI connect to) does not support virtual tables or the audit table, at this time, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/dataverse-sql-query).

I recommend trying the [SQL2CDS plugin](https://markcarrington.dev/sql-4-cds/) for [XRMToolbox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/). This should allow you to get the experience of SSMS on the virtual tables as it will use the API endpoint instead of the TDS endpoint.